# How to use SVG like content loader in NativeScript Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I using NativeScript Vue and wanted to show a loading animation in my components like the https://github.com/egoist/vue-content-loader.

The vue-content-loader package unfortunately don't work for NativeScript, because it uses SVG elements which are not supported in the views.

```html
<template>
  <content-loader
    :height="160"
    :width="400"
    :speed="2"
    primaryColor="#f3f3f3"
    secondaryColor="#ecebeb"
  >
    <rect x="70" y="15" rx="4" ry="4" width="117" height="6.4" /> 
    <rect x="70" y="35" rx="3" ry="3" width="85" height="6.4" /> 
    <rect x="0" y="80" rx="3" ry="3" width="350" height="6.4" /> 
    <rect x="0" y="100" rx="3" ry="3" width="380" height="6.4" /> 
    <rect x="0" y="120" rx="3" ry="3" width="201" height="6.4" /> 
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
  </content-loader>
</template>

<script>
  import { ContentLoader } from "vue-content-loader"

  export default {
    components: {
      ContentLoader
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <svg> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
found in
---> <Home>
<Page>
<App> at components/App.vue
```

Are there any alternatives to vue-content-loader to get a similar animation? Or is there a way to run the vue-content-loader package inside NativeScript Vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Understanding the architecture (NativeScript !== Cordova / PhoneGap):**

Cordova / PhoneGap hosts your web app inside a WebView, all your UI components are just the same HTML DOM Elements.

NativeScript allows your to reuse your web development skills (JavaScript / XML / CSS) to build native mobile app. All the UI components are just same as native, as if you are building an app with Objective C / Java.

The JavaScript runtime allows you to execute any code that is browser independent (CommonJS). You will not have access browser dependent objects like HTML DOM / Canvas / SVG / Document / Window etc., Therefore you can not use *vue-content-loader* in NativeScript which heavily depends on SVG.

**What you are looking for:**

I believe you are looking for Skeleton view, unfortunately there is no ready made plugin available. But you could write one / simply use the relevant native library in your project.

- [SkeletonView for iOS](https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView)
- [SkeletonView for Android](https://github.com/ethanhua/Skeleton)

Refer the [plugin docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins) for more info.

There is also a [blog post](https://dev.to/_joshsommer/nativescript-listview-skeletons-in-angular--rxjs--1m3d) explaining how you could do this in NativeScript with Angular, you may translate it into Vue.